# How to use lattice in Rpy2 and save result to pdf?

Tags: python, r, lattice, rpy2

I am following the documentation for rpy2 here (http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/graphics.html?highlight=lattice).  I can successfully plot interactively using `lattice` from rpy2, e.g.:

```
iris = r('iris')
p = lattice.xyplot(Formula("Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width"),
                   data=iris)
rprint = robj.globalenv.get("print")
rprint(p)
```

`rprint` displays the graph. However, when I try to save the graph to pdf by first doing:

`r.pdf("myfile.pdf")`

and then my `lattice` calls, it does not work and instead results in an empty pdf. If I do the same (call `r.pdf`, then plot) with `ggplot2` or with the R base, then I get a working pdf. Does `lattice` require anything special from within Rpy2 to save the results to a PDF file? The following does not work either:

```
iris = r('iris')
r.pdf("myfile.pdf")
grdevices = importr('grDevices')
p = lattice.xyplot(Formula("Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width"),
                   data=iris)
rprint = robj.globalenv.get("print")
rprint(p)
grdevices.dev_off()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need some equivalent of `dev.off()` after the print command.

That is, in order to save your graphs to pdf, the general outline is:

```
pdf(...)
print(....)
dev.off()
```

Failing to call `dev.off()` will result in an empty pdf file.

---

from [this source](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/graphics.html), it appears that the equivalent in `rpy2` might be

```
grdevices.dev_off()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it (see edits) but it still produces an empty plot

Comment: @user248237, does it still not work? (If so, perhaps remove the check mark).  If it's still a problem, just for kicks try the following:  Where you are calling `grdevices.dev_off()`, instead of calling it once, call it 2 or 3 times repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use:

```
robjects.r["dev.off"]()
```

For some reason the other variants do not do the trick.

Comment: `grdevices.dev_off()` in rpy2 is stricly equivalent to `grDevices::dev.off()`, itself equivalent to `robjects.r["dev.off"]()` if not user-defined function called `dev.off` is present in R's global environment. You may want to check the working environment and code used when making the tests.